# Caliburn.Micro 2.0 .Net targeted framework

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

It's right to say that:
Caliburn.Micro 1.5.x supports .Net frameworks <= 4.0 and Caliburn.Micro 2.0 supports .Net framework <= 4.5? Targeting my applications for .Net 4.0 framework, I can safely updates my apps from CM 1.5.2 to 2.0?

Comment: Why don't you try it out?

Comment: My question born because, for I knew CM 2.x was only targeted for .NET 4.5 [see this](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/468655). But nuget tell me that I can update my projects from 1.5.2 to 2.0 and this is strange for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CM 2.0 supports NET40 (see https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/releases).